Trouble implementing redis cache in php laminas
I have installed php redis in my local system and have added the redis adapter via the composer command:
composer require laminas/laminas-cache-storage-adapter-redis
I tried following this documentation:
https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-cache/v3/storage/adapter/#redis-adapter
I am having trouble setting up the service and the factory files for the same
So far I have defined the options in a config file 'redis.local.php':
return [
    'redis-cache' => [
        'adapter' => [
            'name' => 'redis',
            'options' => [
                'ttl' => 3600,
                'server' => [
                    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                    'port' => 6379,
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'plugins' => [
            [
                'name' => 'exception_handler',
                'options' => [
                    'throw_exceptions' => true,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]
];

and tried to add the options via the factory:
class RedisCacheServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, ?array $options = null): RedisCacheService
    {
        $config = $container->get('config');

        return new RedisCacheService($config['redis-cache']);
    }
} 

and then try to typecast it as a StorageInterFace object (might be doing something wrong here):
class RedisCacheService
{
    public function __construct(private StorageInterface $cacheStorage)
    {
    }
}

